# Лексический повтор (задание № 24 ЕГЭ)

Tags: синтаксис, лексика, егэ

В задании № 24 одного из тренировочных вариантов ЕГЭ требуется найти предложение(-ия), которое(-ые) связано(-ы) с предыдущим с помощью сочинительного союза, лексического повтора и указательного местоимения, в этом фрагменте текста:

> (1) Ваш до боли взволнованный голос, Ваша прядь снежных волос, теплота Вашей ладони, взрыв в моем внутреннем мире…
>
> (2) Но тайна Момента Истины остается тайной!
>
> (3) Может быть, это и есть интуиция, Божественная педагогика, педагогическая искра Божия, Божий дар? (4) И кому дается Искра эта: только избранным или всем?
>
> (5) Вас уже давно нет в живых, любимый мой человек, но я все хожу по вашим тропам и ищу разгадку той Святой минуты, названной мною Моментом Педагогической Истины, когда благой учитель свершает ЧУДО.

Я выбрал третье предложение и оказался неправ. Какой же правильный ответ? Почему?

Comment: Aer♦, это официальные тесты?

Comment: @Серж это Сенина (2018)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В предложении 3 нет никаких связей с предшествующим предложением. А вот в четвертом есть.

(3) Может быть, это и есть интуиция, Божественная педагогика, педагогическая **искра** Божия, Божий дар? (4) **И** кому дается **Искра эта:** только избранным или всем?

Предложение 4 связано с предыдущим при помощи сочинительного союза **и,** лексического повтора (слово искра), и указательного местоимения (эта).

Поэтому правильный ответ: 4.